# Why is Prussian blue ‘blue’ in colour?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, coordination-compounds, transition-metals, color

Potassium ferrocyanide $(\ce{K4[Fe(CN)6]})$ is used for the qualitative analysis of ferric $(\ce{Fe^3+})$ salts. It precipitates as Prussian blue $(\ce{Fe4[Fe(CN)6]3})$.

How to explain the blue colour of Prussian blue? May the colour be due to the charge transfer between a ligand and the central atom?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Prussian blue contains both $\ce{Fe(II)}$ and $\ce{Fe(III)}$. Mixed-valence compounds, such as the one in question, absorb certain wavelengths of visible light resulting due to the phenomenon of inter valence charge transfer (IVCT). 
General Scheme for IVCT is:
$$\ce{L_nM^+-bridge-M'L_n + h\nu ->L_nM-bridge-M'+L_n}$$

In this case, orange-red light around $680\ \mathrm{nm}$ in wavelength is absorbed, and the reflected light appears blue as a result.

Additionally, changes colour from blue to colourless upon reduction. This change is caused due reduction of the $\ce{Fe(III)}$ to $\ce{Fe(II)}$, and thereby eliminating the IVCT responsible for Prussian blue's namesake blue colour. This is also why Prussian Blue exhibitis electrochromic behaviour.

For a more detailed description read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intervalence_charge_transfer#cite_note-1) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_sphere_electron_transfer). Alternatively, you can look it up in a textbook.

Answer (score 3):

From the wikipedia article of [potassium ferrocyanide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prussian_blue):

> The intense blue color of Prussian blue is associated with the energy
>   of the transfer of electrons from Fe(II) to Fe(III). Many such
>   mixed-valence compounds absorb certain wavelengths of visible light
>   resulting from intervalence charge transfer. In this case, orange-red
>   light around 680 nanometers in wavelength is absorbed, and the
>   reflected light appears blue as a result(...)Prussian Blue is
>   electrochromic—changing from blue to colorless upon reduction. This
>   change is caused by reduction of the Fe(III) to Fe(II) eliminating the
>   intervalence charge transfer that causes Prussian blue's color.